# How do I setup the shopify draggable library properly?

Tags: javascript, shopify, draggable

I am trying to create a UI with several boxes hovering over the other elements, with each box having a drag handle. When the user uses the drag handle on any box, they should be able to drag the box anywhere on the page.

To provide this interaction, I am using the draggable library by Shopify, but I'm unclear on a few things:

1. I have gotten to the point where I can drag a box using the appropriate drag handle, but the box is duplicated and the duplicated copy is dragged. How do I hide the original copy of the box so that only the version being dragged is shown? Is this something I have to handle on my own?
2. When the handle is released, the box does not move to the new location and instead snaps back to the original location. Do I need to use the droppable library to be able to move the box to a droppable section? If I want to be able to place the box anywhere on my page (as a hovering element), would the entire body be the droppable selector? Currently this does not seem to work.

My current code is:

```
var containers = document.querySelectorAll('.box');

var droppable = new Draggable.Draggable(containers, {
  draggable: '.box',
  handle: '.drag-handle',
  delay: 0,
});

droppable.on('drag:start', () => console.log('drag:start'));
droppable.on('droppable:over', () => console.log('droppable:over'));
droppable.on('droppable:out', () => console.log('droppable:out'));
```

and I've created a codepen here:
https://codepen.io/khalidadil/pen/QJGVrP

Comment: Wow. I love people that release libraries with code like Draggable.Draggable. Makes one wonder about the power of their weed where they live. Must be super stuff!

Comment: Agreed that it's confusing. I believe in the beta release they've renamed this!